# Files and folders on root folder on the server lose first character when downloaded through Remote-FTP on Atom

Tags: ftp, sftp, atom-editor, remote-access

I am using the Remote-FTP package in Atom. Uploads work as they should, updating the right file in the right folder on the server but when I download a file or a folder from the server to my PC the first folder is missing its first character, causing all sorts of problems. The trees are identical on server and PC.

**Folder example**

I have the file */everything/older/somefile.php* on the server. I right click on the filename on the tree in Atom and select download. Remote-FTP, instead of updating my local */everything/older/somefile.php* file, it creates */verything/older/somefile.php*. The first character (e) is eliminated from the first folder of the path. From *everything/...* to *verything/...*.

**File Example**

I have the file *somefile.php* in the root folder on the server. When I download it, Remote-FTP creates a new file called *omefile.php*. The first character is eliminated.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I have been trying for a long time to find the cause of this with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the root path on the server was causing this. I changed the literal path to the *short cut* version and the problem was gone. I still do not understand why this was happening but was able to solve it through trial and error.